# iAd is killing the performance of my app

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I've developed an app for iOS with `Swift` and now I'd like to add an `ADBannerView` in my `tableviewcontroller` just to show some `iAd banners`.
This is what I did :

1. I linked the iAd framework
2. In the `ViewDidLoad` of my `tableviewcontroller` I have added the following code :

   self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

Quite easy! Perhaps too easy, because everything seemed to work fine, the view displayed the ad correctly but... performance was really bad!! My tableview scrolls smooth if I don't show the ad and keeps lagging while the ad is displayed... how come? What have I missed?

Thanks a lot

D.

Comment: Done any performance profiling?

Comment: I'm pretty much certain that it's not the ad. Profile it with Instruments and check where the bottle neck is. Then show the code that's causing the slowdown.

Comment: Ok, I will try and let you know. But I'm quite sure that it's because of the ad. I know that because if I kill my app, go to the developer section of the preferences and set the fill rate of the iAd to 0% (Always Error) the app works incredibly fast and I have no lag at all. That's really strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help, I was totally wrong, iAd wasn't the cause of slowness of my app.

I've found the problem (I was setting the font of a textbox inside the cellforrowatindexpath method).

I've upvoted your comments because they were the correct way to find the issue.

thanks again
All the best

D.